# HTML5 Canvas: Код кнопки, ведущей на веб-страницу

Tags: html5, button, animate, html5-canvas, яндекс-дисплей

Делаю рекламный баннер, но модерация Яндекс.Дисплея не пропускает, так как переход на целевую веб-страницу с баннера осуществляется всеми кнопками мыши, когда нужно только левой.

**Adobe animate** предлагает следующий фрагмент кода для кнопки, ведущей на веб-страницу (при нажатии любой кнопкой мыши):

```
/* Нажмите для перехода к веб-странице При нажатии на указанный
экземпляр символа производится загрузка веб-страницы в новом окне
обозревателя. Инструкции:
1. Замените http://www.adobe.com на адрес желаемой веб-страницы. Не удаляйте кавычки ("").
*/ this.button_2.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage); function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage() { window.open("http://google.ru",
"_blank"); }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить его, чтобы переход осуществлялся только левой копкой мыши.

P.S. замена `click` на `onСlick` не работает. В итоге переход вообще не осуществляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие Canvas срабатывает при клике на любой кнопке мыши, но можно получить стандартный [объект события MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) и выяснить, какая кнопка мыши были нажата. Если нужна только левая, то ее код равен нулю.

```
this.button_2.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage); 

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event) 
{ 
    if(event.nativeEvent.button == 0)
    {
        window.open("http://google.ru", "_blank"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, это работает.

Answer (score 0):

Нашла еще одно решение проблемы. В HTML-документе вставить следующий код:

```
<script>
function getUrlParam(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
  results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
</script>

<style>*{margin:0;padding:0;}</style>      

<title>HTML5_Ad_Demo</title>
</head>    

<body>
<a id="click1_area" href="#" target="_blank" style="width: 240px; height: 400px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; z-index: 9;"></a>

<script>
    document.getElementById("click1_area").href = getUrlParam('link1');
</script>
```